# How to find nearest ftp server using any tools such as ping,wget etc

Tags: ftp

My requirement is like this. 
We have ftp servers on different locations like USA,India,China. So the users from respective countries download some softwares from those ftp servers. This is manual process, no problem

In automation process, we want to pick the nearest ftp server for the machine respective to location.
My idea is that based on ping response time, i can pick the nearest server.

is there any better solutions or can this idea achievable or not ?

Comment: What you suggested might work. What exactly is your question?  "How to find the server closest to the user" is a frequently asked question, have you tried to use the search?

Answer (score 0):

Ping response time is good parameter in a stable connection. Maybe you can add the ftp server IP address as a parameter, because you can look up IP address and find where it's location. So first try to determine the ftp server based on it's IP address and then get ping response time. If the ping response is not good, move to another server to ensure the quality of the connection.